# Как сделать переход по клику используя Vue-router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Как можно при клике на таб переходить на нужную страницу? Проблему с моим кодом в то что url меняется но не переходит.

```
    listTasks.vue
      <template>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, index) in tabs" :key="index">
                        <a class="nav-link active" @click="$router.push( `${item.path}` )">{{item.name}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
<router-view></router-view>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
        export default {
            data() {
                return {
                    tabs: [
                        {
                            name: 'angular',
                            path: '/tasks/angular'
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'react',
                            path: '/tasks/react'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    </script>

Angular.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <p>angular page</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>

React.vue
<template>
    <div>
        <p>react page</p>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {}
</script>

    router.js
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

    import listTasks from '../views/Tasks/listTasks';
    import Angular from '../views/Tasks/Angular';
    import React from '../views/Tasks/React';

    Vue.use(VueRouter);

    const router = new VueRouter({
        mode: 'history',
        routes: [
            {
                path: '/tasks',
                name: 'tasks',
                component: listTasks,
                children: [
                    {
                        path: 'angular',
                        name: 'angular',
                        component: Angular
                    },
                    {
                        path: 'react',
                        name: 'react',
                        component: React
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    });

    export default router;
```

Comment: И в консоли ошибок нет?

Comment: нет, ошибок нет, url в браузере меняеться на tasks/react но остаюсь на странице tasks

Comment: нет, не пустые обновил, код  в вопросе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При использовании опции `children` в маршруте `tasks`, необходимо задавать свой родительский `router-view` в компоненте `listTasks` для отображения дочерних маршрутов.

```js
// 1в Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

// 2. Определяем компоненты для маршрутов.
const Home = {
  template: '<div>Домашняя страница</div>'
}
const Angular = {
  template: '<div>Angular</div>'
}
const React = {
  template: '<div>React</div>'
}

const listTasks = {
  template: `
        <div>
            <h3>Информация на родительской странице Tasks.</h3>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, index) in tabs">
                    <router-link :to="{ name: item.name}" class="nav-link">{{ item.name }}</router-link>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!-- !!! В этом view будут отображаться дочерние компоненты !!! -->
            <router-view></router-view>
        </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      tabs: [{
        name: 'angular',
        path: '/tasks/angular'
      }, {
        name: 'react',
        path: '/tasks/react'
      }]
    }
  },
}

// // 3. Определяем маршруты.
const routes = [{
  path: '/',
  name: 'home',
  component: Home
}, {
  path: '/tasks',
  name: 'tasks',
  component: listTasks,
  children: [{
      path: 'angular',
      name: 'angular',
      component: Angular
    },
    {
      path: 'react',
      name: 'react',
      component: React
    }
  ]
}]

// 4. Создаём экземпляр маршрутизатора
// и передаём маршруты.
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  pathToRegexOptions: {
    strict: true
  },
  linkActiveClass: 'active',
})

// 5. Создаём экземпляр приложения.
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  data: {}
})
```

```css
ul {
  width: 250px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

li a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/" exact>Home</router-link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <router-link to="/tasks">Tasks</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- View верхнего уровня. -->
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>

<!-- 1а. Подключаем vue -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<!-- 1б. Подключаем vue-roter -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-router@3.0.6"></script>
```

Для того, чтобы один из дочерних компонентов отражался без предварительного выбора со стороны пользователя:

```
routes: [{
  path: '/tasks',
  name: 'tasks',
  component: listTasks,
    children: [{
      // Теперь по умолчанию
      // будет показан Angular
      path: '',
      name: 'angular',
      component: Angular
    }, {

      // ...остальные вложенные маршруты
    }]
  }]
```

Comment: Подскажи пожалуйста ещё код теперь работает но когда я сразу закожу на localhost/tasks то мне нужно обновить страницу чтобы первый таб начал рендериться либо на сам таб нажать, как это можно поправить?

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="nav-item" v-for="(item, index) in tabs" :key="index">
   <router-link :to="item.path" tag="a">{{ item.name }}</router-link>         
</li>
```

Так пробовали?
Либо же, ещё может быть проблема в том, что у ссылки есть дефолтное поведение, которое надо убрать добавление модификатора **.prevent** к событию `@click`:

```
@click.prevent="$router.push( `${item.path}` )"
```

Comment: Да, пробывал тоже самое что и с моим кодом, url меняеть но остаюсь на прежней странице

Comment: @DimaVleskov поправил

Answer (score 0):

Я для себя решаю проблему тем, что добавляю `location.reload`:

```
  methods: {
    saveForm() {
      this.request('/Account/Create', { account: this.account }, () => {});

      this.$router.push('/');
      location.reload();
    },
  },
```

Обратите внимание ещё на две вещи:

- вы пишете js-код прямо в шаблоне, я бы оставил там только название функции, чтобы строка не вышла слишком длинной
- вместо html-элемента `<a` лучше использовать `<router-link`